# User unable to see a column in a report

Tags: reporting

As an admin I have created a report and saved the same in a shared folder which is accessible by specific Users.(Basically a Public Group)

When I log in as one of the user I can see the report but it's missing one of the column, which as a user I am able to add when I customize the report.

May I know what could be the reason the user is  unable to see one of the report's column in first place ?

Regards,
Ata.

Answer (score 3):

Check the field level security for that user's profile by navigating:

Setup-> Your object -> fields -> Your field -> field level security.

Makes sure that your field is visible to users profile.